# MySQL update value in column when there is particular text in two other

Tags: mysql

I have phpmyadmin page and I must alter many rows in my database. I have table 'lime_answers', and inside I have **answer** and **language** columns. What I want to do is to update all answers that are, lets say "littlepony" to "bigpony", but only when language column has "en" in that row. So something like

```
SELECT * FROM 'lime_answers' WHERE ('answer' = 'littlepony' AND 'language' = 'en') 
then SET 'answer' = 'bigpony'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
update lime_answers set answer = 'bigpony' where answer = 'littlepony' AND language = 'en'
```

Comment: This one worked, thank you very much Christian, you have saved me something like 4 hours of boring work :))))

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this


 update 'lime_answers' set 'answer' = 'bigpony'
    where ('answer' = 'littlepony' AND 'language' = 'en')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE lime_answers SET `answer` = 'bigpony' WHERE (`answer` = 'littlepony' AND `language` = 'en')
```

Use this